# Accessing a Facebook page as an administrator after account cancelation

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

This is a purely theoretical question but what happens if a Facebook page has only one admin and his or her account gets cancelled, for example due to terms of use violation? Is the page removed from Facebook? Is there any way to still manage it?

Comment: +1 nice question.. I guess you will get an answer from the FB creator :)

Comment: Contacting Mr. Zuckerberg is as hard as contacting Facebook in general :-)

Comment: Lol.. Thats true:) but still this question is tuff to answer!

Answer (score 1):

to my understanding if there is only one admin and his account gets cancelled, the page will be deleted.

I know this is true for the old groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can add one or more administrators to a Facebook page. That means the administrator is not necessarily the owner of the page.

Should the account of the owner be removed, the page would be removed as well. If you have a page and the administrator does not exist anymore, your only way to get access is Facebook support.

Comment: I am not sure it works this way. I have had one personal account blocked already and it did not cause one of the fan pages I have created to be removed, other admins were still able to manage it and add my new account to the admin list. Facebook has not seemed to care I was the original creator of the page.